# Exception "Hybrid player not valid" when trying to deploy an app using Azure Remote Rendering to Hololens2

Tags: hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality, azure-remote-rendering

I am developing an app for Hololens2 with Unity, Mixed Reality Toolkit and Azure Remote Rendering. Something with ARR (probably a misconfiguration) produces a deploy-time error:

```
 *** Assertion ***

    Expression: "hybridPlayer"
    Function: "RemotingXrLayerXrCreateApiLayerInstance"
    File: "D:\a\_work\1\s\src\libstreamer\hybrid\HybridPlayerOpenXrLayer.cpp"
    Line: 1480
    Message: "Hybrid player not valid."
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFAF0BFACC4 (Microsoft.Holographic.HybridRemoting.dll) in hololens-<redacted>-unity.exe: 0xC0000602:
```

Does anyone have any idea where this could come from? My rendering pipeline is set to `HybridRenderingPipeline`, and my MRTK profile to `ARRMixedRealityToolkitConfigurationProfile`.

I will happily provide more information. It's just that at the moment I don't know what information is relevant to the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regression in the latest Azure Remote Rendering SDK. Please go back to [Version 1.0.41](https://github.com/Azure/azure-remote-rendering/releases/tag/1.0.41) for now. This should be fixed with the next release.

Comment: Just for future, where did you get this information from? Their issue tracker seems to mention other problems with 1.0.47 but nothing related to this...

Comment: @K.Raivio I'm working on Azure Remote Rendering. GitHub issues and [HoloDevelopers Azure Slack Channel](https://holodevelopers.slack.com/archives/CFTRE4CAU/p1644931793032399?thread_ts=1644599701.746379&cid=CFTRE4CAU) are good places to look for issues. We do check stackoverflow as well daily so feel free to ask questions here as well.